# How to catch solidity contract revert message using web3j (Java)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, web3j, revert-opcode

Is there any way to catch solidity revert message like Remix Javascript VM in **web3j (Java)**

**Revert message(Remix)**

```
transact to Erecruitment.issueNewAdmitCard errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Reason provided by the contract: "Admit card ID already exists in Blockchain".  Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

**Event message (Remix)**

```
 logs   [
    {
        "from": "0x692a70d2e424a56d2c6c27aa97d1a86395877b3a",
        "topic": "0xbf970614f4ff9483c34fa1a053bc6614e06003a1faef2d0876e9255bfa3167fc",
        "event": "LogIssueNewCard",
        "args": {
            "0": "2",
            "1": "4",
            "2": "New Card is issued in Blockchain",
            "admitCardId": "2",
            "applicantName": "4",
            "message": "New Card is issued in Blockchain",
            "length": 3
        }
    }
]
```

I get event messages for successful transactions in web3j. So, I can be sure that whether my transaction is completed without any error. If transaction is reverted there will be no event as usual(it's ok). But I am not getting any revert message too for a failed transaction.

And I am getting transaction status `null` each and every time using web3j as **byzantiumBlock** is missing in my genesis file. Then how can I check the transaction status?

Answer (score 6):

In solidity 0.4.22 the `require` and `revert` reason were added. As can be seen [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/pull/3364/files#diff-6ec42630506b86abb9d7386116dd0e5bR85), they are abi-encoded as if it were a call to a function "Error(string)".

You'll need to make an `eth_call` to your contract.

[This blog post](https://www.dhondt.tech/blog/2019/1/Web3j-retrieve-revert-reason.html) gives an example: an `eth_call` to a function

```
function myFunction(uint256 input) public view returns (uint256) {
    require(input >= 5, "myFunction only accepts arguments which are greather than or equal to 5");
    return input * input - 25;
}
```

with an invalid input argument (less than 5 in this example), will return

```
0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000476d7946756e6374696f6e206f6e6c79206163636570747320617267756d656e747320776869636820617265206772656174686572207468616e206f7220657175616c20746f203500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which is

```
0x08c379a0                                                       // Function selector
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020 // Offset of string return value
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000047 // Length of string return value (the revert reason)
6d7946756e6374696f6e206f6e6c79206163636570747320617267756d656e74 // first 32 bytes of the revert reason
7320776869636820617265206772656174686572207468616e206f7220657175 // next 32 bytes of the revert reason
616c20746f203500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 // last 7 bytes of the revert reason
```

So decoding the returned string will give you the revert reason.

With Web3j this could be done like:

```
public Optional<String> getRevertReason(EthCall ethCall) {
    String errorMethodId = "0x08c379a0"; // Numeric.toHexString(Hash.sha3("Error(string)".getBytes())).substring(0, 10)
    List<TypeReference<Type>> revertReasonTypes = Collections.singletonList(TypeReference.create((Class<Type>) AbiTypes.getType("string")));

    if (!ethCall.hasError() && ethCall.getValue() != null && ethCall.getValue().startsWith(errorMethodId)) {
        String encodedRevertReason = ethCall.getValue().substring(errorMethodId.length());
        List<Type> decoded = FunctionReturnDecoder.decode(encodedRevertReason, revertReasonTypes);
        Utf8String decodedRevertReason = (Utf8String) decoded.get(0);
        return Optional.of(decodedRevertReason.getValue());
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that getting the revert message is possible with web3j, however I get the status of my transactions with this command (but ofc you should wait until the transaction is mined and your Node is synchronized)

```
EthGetTransactionReceipt transactionReceipt = web3j.ethGetTransactionReceipt("The Hash of your Transaction").send();
    if (transactionReceipt.getResult() != null && !transactionReceipt.hasError()) {
        System.out.println(transactionReceipt.getTransactionReceipt().get().getStatus());
    } else {
      "TRY AGAIN SOMEHOW LATER.. :-)"
    }
```

For your question about events, I think in the generated smart contract wrappers  there is event methods that you can easily use.
see : https://docs.web3j.io/smart_contracts.html

Comment: I appreciate your answer but you will get result for every mined transaction but may not get result field ( as it depends on byzantiumBlock field in genesis file). I agree that events may help you but event will not be triggered unless it is executed that is execution reached to that line. what do your think?

Comment: Yes with events you can't be sure if your transaction failed or just stuck. I have not tried it yet, but maybe you can somehow use a FailedEvent that got emitted when (Admit card ID already exists in Blockchain), and undo what happend before that emit.

Comment: @sharif2008 maybe that could help somehow: I was using Ganache with automine then this code gave me the revert message                                             
                                                                                                   
EthSendTransaction transactionTx = web3j.ethSendRawTransaction(sigendTransactionData).sendAsync().get();          
if (transactionTx.hasError()) { System.out.println(transactionTx.getError().getMessage() ); }

Answer (score 1):

As of web3j 4.6 the RevertReasonExtractor class exists for this purpose

```
import org.web3j.utils.RevertReasonExtractor;
...
  String revertReason;
  try {
    revertReason = RevertReasonExtractor.extractRevertReason(
                                              transactionReceipt,
                                              inputData,
                                              web3,
                                              true);
  } catch (IOException e) {
     revertReason="?? could not reach network " + e.getMessage();
  }
  return(revertReason);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an NPM package for just this reason: [eth-revert-reason](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eth-revert-reason)

---

It is difficult to decode the revert reason in a general manner. Many different factors, such as Parity vs. Geth, ethers vs. web3.js, etc. will result in different results. Some issues are:

1. For a Kovan transaction, you need a custom provider that exposes Parity `trace` methods.
2. Transactions may result in different messages depending on the context of the block they are called from. Because of this, you may need to be running a full-archival node in order to retrieve the correct error message.

In a happy-path case, the code to retrieve the revert reason is:

```
const provider = customProvider || ethers.getDefaultProvider(network)
const tx = await provider.getTransaction(txHash)
const code = await provider.call(tx)
```

While the code to produce the revert reason in the normal case is simple, the non-standard cases are surprisingly difficult to handle, however this package attempts to appease this.